# How can I test the read speed of a RAID1 device?

Tags: raid, raid1, performance

Some RAID controllers speed-up read access when using RAID1. Other controllers can't do that.

Trying some RAID1 configurations, I want to know if the read speed is faster both on a single file and on several files.

There are plenty of tools which test the read/write speed of a hard drive. What about testing a RAID speed, including software RAID? Are there any tools for Windows which can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of utilities out there, you don't say what OS so here are a few:

[bonnie](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/bonnie/) (Linux)
[HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) (Windows)
[Intel IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/) (Windows & Linux)

Also the tools that test a single hard drive will work just as well against a raid volume.

Comment: HD Tune tests the speed of hard disk, so it bypass the software RAID (and probably the hardware RAID too). Does Intel IOMeter do the same?

Comment: @MainMa I never use software raid so i can't give you definitive answer. I know HD Tune doesn't bypass the hardware raid (it's what i used to benchmark my work desktop w/ hardware raid for fun.)

Comment: IOMeter can do a good job modeling real-world workloads. I highly recommend it. It won't "bypass" any RAID functionality. It reads and writes to files thru the standard Windows (or Linux) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

bonnie?

http://www.textuality.com/bonnie/

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say that I'm using Windows.